# Angularjs: how to change routing hashtag # to #!

Tags: angularjs, hashtag

Can I change the default Angular routing hashtag `#` to `#!`?

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/:module/:method/",
    {
        templateUrl: "template/app.html",
        controller: "AppCtrl2"
    });
});
```

the routing code above is meant for an url like,

```
http://localhost/myapp/#/page/summary/
```

what about if I want my hashtag url to be like this below?

```
http://localhost/myapp/#!page/summary/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messing with the location provider should do the trick.

```
app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
});
```

Comment: thanks but angular keeps forcing the url to `#!/page/summary/` instead of just `#!page/summary/`

Comment: I think you're going to have to just live with that unfortunately. I think, but am not certain, that that's how the framework works. You'd be fighting really hard against it to make it work another way.

The router and the sort expect a fully formed directory structure style url, so you might be able to look there if you want to cheat it.